# How to show 1:node in VScode terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, terminal

Hello I was wondering how do I show the 1:node function in the terminal? Where the bash function is at? [here is my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XURKl.png). I have installed Node.js but I do not know why it is not showing up. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your script is running via Node. So I don't understand your question. Click [Terminal] in the top menu, then click [New Terminal Window], then in the new terminal window at the bottom type `node -v` - it should return the version #.

Comment: Yes I have installed it and the version showed. But how do I make the 1:node show where the bash is that in the terminal? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: ah, you mean on the into bar at the top right? Click the arrow next to `bash`. That will provide you a list of all the open terminal windows. The newer version actually list them in a panel on the right.

Comment: https://ibb.co/KVW9VB2 This is what my terminal shows when I do so. Is there something I missed when I installed node?

Comment: Wrong arrow. Why don't you back up two steps and start reading the documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-terminals Good luck to you.

Comment: Oh sorry about that here it is. https://ibb.co/92CdXdb. I will also read the document.